# Связь многие ко многим Entity Framework Asp Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

У меня возникла проблема с реализацией этой связи. Как делаю я

Есть две модели класс поставщики

```
public class Supplier
    {
        [Display(Name = "SupplierID")]
        [Key]
        public int SupplierID { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Коммерческое название")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        public string Name { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Бренд")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        public string ShortName { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Сайт")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        public string Site { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "ИНН")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        public string Inn { set; get; }

        public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
    }
```

И класс оказываемых ими услуг

```
 public class Service
    {
        [Display(Name = "ServiceID")]
        [Key]
        public int ServiceID { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Название услуги")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        public string Service_Name { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

    }
```

В контексте я создаю слой данных.

```
 public class Context : DbContext
    {

        public Context() : base("Jumper")
        {}
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();


            modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasMany<Service>(s => s.Services).WithMany(c => c.Suppliers).Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("SupplierID");
                m.MapRightKey("ServiceID");
                m.ToTable("SupplierServiceMap");
            });

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }

    }
```

И наполняю таблицу данными, все ок. Теперь пытаюсь все вывести во View
и тут начинается проблема, для этих я создаю ModelView, вот такого вида

```
 public class SuppliersView
    {
        public IEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
    }
```

Затем в контролере все собираю

```
     public ActionResult Index()
            {

                var suppliers = db.Suppliers.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
                var services = db.Services.ToList();

                var model = new SuppliersView
                {
                  Suppliers = suppliers,
                  Services = services
                };


                return View(model);
}
```

И вот View

```
@model Jumper.ViewModel.SuppliersView
     @foreach (var s in Model.Suppliers)
{
    <div class="ui card">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="right floated" style="display:none" id="delete_or_edit">
                <i class="circular inverted link edit icon"></i>
                <i class="circular inverted link delete icon"></i>
            </div>
            <h2 class="header">@s.ShortName</h2>
            <div class="meta" style="font-size: 0.92857143rem; ">
                <span style="color:black">@s.Name</span><br />
                <span>ИНН: @s.Inn</span>
            </div>
            <div style="font-weight:700; font-size: 0.92857143rem; margin-top:1em;">
                <i class="phone icon"></i> @s.Site <br />
                <i class="mail icon"></i> @s.Site <br />
                <a href="http://@s.Site" target="_blank"><i class="world icon"></i> @s.Site</a> <br />
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="ui small feed">
                <div class="event">

                </div>

                <div class="event">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="summary">
                          @foreach (var srv in Model.Services) {
                            <a class="ui tag label">@srv.Service_Name</a>

                          }
```

**Почему при запуске проекта все существующие в базе услуги выводятся на экран?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в базе данных данному поставщику я добавил только две услуги 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы ,что бы он вывел на экран только Ремонт и Оргтехника.
Как мне это сделать. Я приблизительно понимаю,что о,шибка в контроллере, который в модель собирает все услуги, а не только те которые предоставляет поставщик.

Comment: Выводит именно так, как вы ему задаёте: получаете список поставщиков и список услуг, которые в `SuppliersView` между собой никак не связаны. Попробуйте во View заменить `@foreach (var srv in Model.Services)` на `@foreach (var srv in s.Services)`. Тогда и строка `var services = db.Services.ToList();` в контроллере не нужна будет.

Comment: предварительно не забудьте материализовать коллекцию `Services`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде модель Вы заполняете всеми услугами `var services = db.Services.ToList();` а надо судя по всему только теми которые оказывает поставщик.

Я бы поступил так:

```
var suppliers = db.Suppliers.Include(x=>x.Services).ToList();
```

т.е. получаем поставщиков и заполняем *навигационное свойство* при помощи конструкции `Include()`. после этого услуги оказываемые поставщиком берем из *навигационного свойства*

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. Выдает такую ошибку.

Comment: @shatoidil необходимо подключить пространство имен `System.Data.Entity`: `using System.Data.Entity;`